# Replace Parent with Child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have snipset like this

```
<div class='wrapper'>
    <div class='head'/>
    <div class='content'>
        <div class='user'/>
        <span class='spam'/>
    </div>
</div>
<div class='wrapper'>
     <div class='head'/>
        <div class='content'>
        <div class='user'/>
        <p class='inner'/>
    </div>
</div>
```

and i want replace parent that contain child which have class spam, so its look like this

```
<span class='spam'/>           
<div class='wrapper'>
    <div class='head'/>
        <div class='content'>
            <div class='user'/>
            <p class='inner'/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please note that `<div>`,`<span>`,`<p>` is not self-closing tag, you need to use `</div>`,`</span>`,`</p>` to close it.

Comment: You can not place block elements into inline element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".wrapper").each(function() {
        var spam = $(this).find(".spam");
        // check if spam element found and replace it with wrapper element
        if(null!=spam && spam .length > 0)
    {
      $(this).replaceWith(hasSpam);
    }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After correct your HTML to make it valid, then you can use `.closest()` along with `.replaceWith()`:

```
$('span.spam').closest('div.wrapper').replaceWith('<span class="spam" />');
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6Z66c/)**